# Modular Exponentiation doesn't work on a prime mod?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

For 83627264^275372 mod 277 using modular exponentiation, I noticed that things weren't lining up when I checked them on Wolfram. So far I have this:

83627264^1 mod 277 = 133
83627264^2 mod 277 = 238
83627264^4 mod 277 = 238^2 mod 7 = 0

But 83627264^4 mod 277 actually equals 136 according to Wolfram.

Am I messing up somewhere obvious or am I missing some step entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: you should mod by $277$, not $7$. Indeed:
$$
83627264^4 \pmod{277} = 238^2 \pmod{277} = 136
$$

Comment: WOW! I knew it was that simple. Thank you kind stranger!